# There is a way to make a request every .txt file line?

Tags: python

I'm doing a roblox name checker. Only except code works.

I've tried things like with open(...)as f:,etc.

```py
with open('usernames.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        a=requests.get('https://api.roblox.com/users/get-by-username?username=%s' % line)
        r=json.loads(a.content)

    try:
        if r["success"]== False:
            print("Username avaliable ["+line+"]")
            f=open("free.txt",'a')
            f.write('n')
            f.close()
     except:
        print("Username taken ["+line+"]")
        file=open("taken.txt",'a')
        file.write(line)
        file.close()
```

Comment: What's the point of ```f.write('n')```?

Comment: As you can see here, it is usually a bad idea to have an `except` clause without specific exception, especially if you have a long `try` block where many different things can go wrong. You can't have a meaningful error message telling you what happened in the `try` block. You could remove it and see what happens...

Comment: Is the indentation here exactly the same as what your actual code has? Because it doesn't make a lot of sense to check `r["success"]` _after_ the loop ends. If you do that, it will only check the last line of the file instead of all of them.

Comment: You are reassigning `f` inside the `with` statement. If you move the `try/except` into the `for` loop as @Kevin suggests, you will get `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file:

```py
with open('usernames.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()
```

now, data is a list with each one of your lines, so you can iterate over it

```
for i in range(0,len(data)):
    username = data[i].replace("\n","")
    a=requests.get('https://api.roblox.com/users/get-by-username?username=%s' % username)
    r=json.loads(a.content)

    try:
        if r["success"]== False:
            print("Username avaliable ["+username+"]")
            f=open("free.txt",'a')
            f.write(username + "\n")
            f.close()
    except:
        print("Username taken ["+username+"]")
        file=open("taken.txt",'a')
        file.write(username + "\n")
        file.close()
```

Try that way; the username variable is to scape the "enter" at the end of each line.

Comment: Now works, I understood what u did. I didn't knew the file.readlines().
thanks